# Which assert method i can use to check whether an array of 1000 elements contains a particular element?

Tags: junit4

I have an integer array of 1000 elements. I have to check whether this array contains a particular element using an assert method?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to search / iterate through the array and set a boolean that you can then test with an assertTrue().

Or if it was an ArrayList(), and not a raw array, you could use:

```
assertTrue(arrayList.contains(XYZ));
```